# How to test Anguar material radio button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is my component :

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="answer" (change)="onAnswer.emit(answer)">
    <mat-radio-button  [value]="AnswerOptions.YES">
        Yes, the price is $ {{ price }}
    </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="AnswerOptions.NO_TAG">
        There is not pricing Tag
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

I want to test that the binding work well, and in the answer I have **yes** or **no**, how can I do it?

I tried raise trigger on click, but nothing happened.

Comment: Could you provide your TS file as well? Also, What I could understand is... you are trying to see the current value of the radio buttons when you are choosing between them, right?

Comment: Need  ts side code for clear the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here I assign the static value to `mat-radio-button`.

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" [(ngModel)]="answer">
  <mat-radio-button value="yes">Yes, the price is $5</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="no">There is not pricing Tag</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<p>
The answer is {{answer}}
</p>
```

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2v8guh?file=src/app/radio-overview-example.html